# How would you modify BFS to find the shortest path from A to B, given that the graph is very large?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-theory

What I mean by "very large graph" is that each vertex has 1000 adjacent vertices, but if you go to see the final solution the distance from A to B was just 6 (say).

In such a situation, using the basic BFS algorithm would be wasteful as it puts all the 1000 of A's adjacent vertices and then in the next round 1000 for each of these and so on..by time I reach B I would have considered 1000^6 vertices..

Any Idea how to optimize? Or rather is there a way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One easy thing to do is to work from both directions:

At each step, do this:

- get new neighbors of nbrsA looking for B, if not found set nbrsA = new neighbors
- get new neighbors of nbrsB looking for A, if not found set nbrsB = new neighbors
- compare nbrsA and nbrsB

If the graph is big but highly connected, then you'll save a fair amount of space this way, but it does cost some extra time to compare the sets of neighbors.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the BFS to use Dijkstras algorithm. BFS and Dijkstras are related in certain ways and so this modification should be acceptable.  And since this was a phone screen there are a lot of chances they wanted you to see the relationship there.

Comment: Dijkstra is for weighted graphs. Otherwise, it boils down to BFS. ...and I assume the OP was talking about unweighted graphs.

Comment: Dijkstra's Algorithm works fine for unweighted graphs. You just give all the paths a weight of "1" while processing.
OR you can take the 1000 edges in a row, and compress them to a single edge of weight 1000. (Though on this last bit, I feel the question is a bit vague.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree,

this is an interesting problem. As far as I can see, there are two things that might help you:

1. Search forward and backwards at the same time. If you really had a minimum degree of 1000, then you would need to investigate 1000^d nodes in the d-th iteration of a BFS. This effectively reduces a 1000^(2d) to a 2*1000^d.
2. At some point BFS will be too expensive in terms of memory consumption. To avoid this you can switch to 'iterative deepening': Emulate a BFS by doing a depth first search (limited to 1 iteration) and then a DFS (limited to 2 iterations), etc. The overhead is a small constant (which of course is not desirable), but this way you can avoid memory problems while discovering nodes in the same order as a BFS would do.

Answer (score 0):

One of two things is true:

Those 1000 vertices are often shared, meaning once they're found in round 1 they will get ignored in round 2 drastically lowering your search field,

OR

Those 1000 verticies are unique meaning you have millions or billions of nodes, meaning you're still on the expected scale of the algorithm.

Either way, not much to do about it.

Comment: Well I wish I could take that answer, I just finished a phone interview 20 mins back, and this was the question they asked me..A few suggestions I gave was, try going all the way 6 levels and then consider the next adjacent vertex. Its not the best idea but somewat better.

Comment: Honestly, this is a very poor interview question. They're asking you to improve one of the most basic and widely used algorithms in computer science. Chances are they have a poorly formed data structure and were just trying to get good ideas from smart people, not realizing their fundamental problem, or they found some clever corner case and are using that as their expected answer. Either way they're not people you want to work for. BFS will find the path in `O(n)`... there isn't much more you can do! If your `n` is big, then your `n` is big... sorry!